# Deploying Schema Registry in production in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, confluent-schema-registry

We want to deploy Confluent Schema Registry in Kubernetes for production setup. Are there any guidelines available specifically related to Kubernetes.I followed these articles.

Schema Registry Single Datacenter Setup
https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/singledc.html

High Availability for Single Primary Setup
https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/index.html#sr-high-availability-single-primary

Also I am referring cp-confluent charts. I would need more info on setting right configurations in production in Kubernetes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema Registry is really just a web service. There isn't much to configure outside of `kafkastore.connection.url`, `kafkastore.topic`, and optional SSL settings. Memory and disk usage is minimal, as per docs - *heap size of **1GB** would be more than sufficient*

The Helm charts provided by Confluent work fine, and you can deploy multiple Registries fronted by an Ingress to perform load-balancing and high-availability

The high level details here apply, regardless of how you deploy it.

https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/installation/deployment.html

Comment: Thanks for responding cricket_007. I would like to deploy in HA mode with 3 replicas. One acting as a leader and others acting as followers. How can I achieve this in Kubernetes .I referred confluent helm charts and replicas is mentioned as 1. In production , I would need more than 1 . How can I achieve this?

Comment: Changing replicas to 3 will spin up 3 pods. Now I am not sure how do I configure these 3 pods such that one pod acts as leader and other 2 act as followers. When a client wants to use schema-registry service I want to make sure always leader pod is discovered even when request is load balanced to follower pods. Basically the pods should discover themselves and act as a cluster and this setup should be accessed by clients using a service name.

Comment: Leadership is automatically handled and pods reach each other through others `listeners` variable. Any registry can handle any client request

Comment: Yes. I tried it today and it works. just setting the hostname to pod ip was enough.Thanks for responding.